# Does StackExchange support 'switching' between two StackExchange accounts (OpenIDs)?

Tags: feature-request, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I would like to make two StackExchange accounts - one for normal use and one for testing my website's OpenID login process. And I would like to switch between these when authenticating. Is there a 'switch account' function (similar to Google's)? I've had a pretty good look and can't find one.

If not, having one would be handy. It would save me from deleting cookies to switch accounts :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not presently supported.

Of course, you can *have* as many accounts as you like, but you'll have to log out of one before logging into another (or use a different browser session).

Comment: Thanks - I get lost on SE a bit so confirming that is good. It took me about 5 mins to find the log out function again just now :-P. Logging out doesn't work because when you log back in it automatically logs you into your last logged in account (I assume stored in a cookie).

Comment: Make sure you're logging out on https://openid.stackexchange.com, since otherwise yeah SE will just log you right back in again. For that matter, if you're just testing OpenID you don't have to log out of SE at all - just log out on openid.se and you'll be able to switch up accounts to your heart's content without ever being logged off here.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not supported by StackExchange,  if using Google Chrome to browse, it's easy to have two users there, to switch between your normal and testing accounts without logging out or clearing the cache.

[image]

To do that, go to Settings - Create user (or `http://chrome://settings/createProfile`):
[image]